# How to show facebook like, share button on blog post

Tags: java, facebook, spring-mvc

Hi i'm going to create a blog web app using java with spring framework.
The admin can post the blog post and users can view the posts on the public URL.
So how do i show like,share buttons on the each and every posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this Link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Important Part of Page is:

```
<!-- Your share button code -->
    <div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
        data-layout="button_count">
    </div>
```

Comment: so do i have to add fb css and js?

Comment: @boycod3 no i don't think so, its works without css and js, and if answer is useful accept it

Comment: let me check before accepting answer, give me sometime.

Comment: How do i isolate particular post content only.

Comment: @boycod3 you have to use post_url only to share into data-href attribute